# When I Put my jFrame at Maximized Both And Not Resizable It Hides Taskbar But Its Good When I only Put it At Maximized Both

Tags: java, user-interface, interface, maximize-window

When I put my JFrame at Maximized Both and Not Resizable, it hides the taskbar, but it's good when I only put it at Maximized Both!

Also there is a problem with setting the icon in the title bar. I tried every method available on the Internet, but it doesn't take effect.

New to Java.

OS - Windows 10 64 Bit
IDE - Apache Netbeans IDE 15
Java Version - 17.0.4.1
Using Java with Gradle for this project

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */
package SVM;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
/**
 *
 * @author VARUN
 */
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("Login");
        setIconImage(new ImageIcon("icon.png").getImage());    
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(7, 12, 7, 12);
        jPanel1.add(jTextField1, gridBagConstraints);

        jPasswordField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jPasswordField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(7, 12, 7, 12);
        jPanel1.add(jPasswordField1, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("CG Times", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Login");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(19, 0, 19, 0);
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SimSun", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Username :");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(6, 0, 6, 0);
        jPanel1.add(jLabel3, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SimSun", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Password :");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(6, 0, 6, 0);
        jPanel1.add(jLabel4, gridBagConstraints);

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SimSun", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Login");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(10, 13, 10, 0);
        jPanel1.add(jButton1, gridBagConstraints);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 617, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 497, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jPasswordField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                               

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Hi, on what OS are you running this example. Running it Fedora did not hide the taskbar. Also, where is your "icon.png"  located?

Comment: Regarding your icon:  read about the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) and relative file paths, which are a general computing concept, not just a Java concept.  You probably want `new ImageIcon(Login.class.getResource("icon.png"))`, so the current working directory won’t matter.

Comment: @swinkler I tried placing my icon.png file in Resources Folder It Didn't work then I tried Placing it in my Package Directory Where Login.java was Located That Didnt Work Either.I Am Running Windows 10 64bit. Using Netbeans IDE 15

Comment: @VGR Yeah I did Try The Code Before Didn't Work For Me. This Was Available on Net. I Even Tried Placing The icon.png File In Different Directories!

Comment: I put it in the project folder for simplicity - it resides next to the src folder etc. As @VGR mentioned, depending on the (final) image location using the resource loading would be preferrable IMHO.